# Url configuration for search engines

Tags: php, html

I need a person who can help me create a url like this `http://www.saqaw.com/AllAds/Other-ladys-Fashion/page=1`
 but not like this

```
http://www.saqaw.com/AllAds/?Ad=Other%20ladys%20Fashion&page=1
```

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework, or just plain PHP? What have you tried?

Comment: You can try mod_rewrite of apache. But you have to explain more about your code.

Comment: This has been asked about 800,000 times here. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of [this ServerFault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a very general question but a quick URL parser may help you:

```
$url = "http://www.saqaw.com/AllAds/?Ad=Other%20ladys%20Fashion&page=1";
    $url = parse_url($url);
    $queries = explode("&", $url['query']);
    $newURL = $url['host'] . $url['path'];
    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        $queryContent = explode("=", $query);
        $queryContent[0] == "Ad"? $newURL .= str_replace("%20", "-", $queryContent[1]):$newURL .= "/".$query;

    }
    echo $newURL;
```

Result

```
www.saqaw.com/AllAds/Other-ladys-Fashion/page=1
```

however if you looking for a more general purpose url parse you can use the script below:

```
$url = "http://www.saqaw.com/AllAds/?Ad=Other%20ladys%20Fashion&page=1";
    $url = parse_url($url);
    $queries = explode("&", $url['query']);
    $newURL = $url['host'] . $url['path'];
    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        $queryContent = explode("=", $query);
        $newURL .= $queryContent[0] . "/" . str_replace("%20", "-", $queryContent[1]) . "/";


    }
    echo $newURL;
```

Result

```
www.saqaw.com/AllAds/Ad/Other-ladys-Fashion/page/1/
```

however the above scripts are quick fixed and does not include security or script injection.